# Migrating from TFS to GIT and want to keep them synced

Tags: git, tfs

We are currently migrating from TFS to GIT. We have moved all branches, so far so good. Problem is that the developers are still working with TFS so any change is pushed to that repo. We need to keep them syncd, which wouldent have been a problem if we wont push to the GIT repo.

But that is not the Case, we have pushed a .gitignore and .attributes file. We have also applied GIT LFS to the repo. These changes have not affected the TFS repo.

But when we use the commmand:

```
git tfs pull -r
```

It over writes our commit.

Thanks for any advice, or question.

Comment: If you commit in git and also checked in in TFVC, you can't make the double synchro without rewriting the git history (it's what `git tfs pull -r` is doing). There is simply no other way!

Comment: I would heavily advise you locate all your developers who are still using TFVC and get them to migrate.
I think the only other way to make something like this would would be to map the tfvc branches to diffrent git branches, and merge like they where git.